# Does TFS make both Symbol and Source server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windbg, debug-symbols

I have read [“What is the difference in TFS 2010 between a source server and symbol server?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658612/what-is-the-difference-in-tfs-2010-between-a-source-server-and-symbol-server)  
I have tried to set up my TFS build definition to generate source and symbol server.  
Like this:
 [image: Build definition]

However, for me the result looks not like a proper symbol server.  
When I open a crash dump, I still need to set symbol path to the correct drop folder where the dll’s (and also another .pdb ) reside.  
In the selected “Path to publish Symbols” I see folders for the .pdb, but not for the .dll.

To be able to debug a dump I know that also the dll’s are needed.

Therefore I suspect my tfs to make only a source server, how can I then also have a symbol server.

Answer (score 4):

TFS is only a Source Server. By specifying a shared path as your symbols store you setup for yourself a Symbols Server where Tfs Build publishes your projects' .pdb files to. The Symbols Server does not contain the binaries. The binaries should either be on the machine where you debug your application or from the build drop location.

Comment: Feature request for TFS to be a Symbol Server: http://www.edsquared.com/2012/02/15/Feature+Request+Treat+TFS+As+An+Enterprise+Symbol+Server.aspx